# Jinja2 incompatible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dbt, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to install dbt into GCP cloud shell, but always receive this message error:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> flask 2.1.1 requires Jinja2>=3.0, but you have jinja2 2.11.3 which is incompatible.

I resetting cloud shell and remove Jinja using `sudo pip3 uninstall Jinja2`, after install dbt `pip3 install dbt-bigquery`. But it shows the same message.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?